# Securely safe credentials in a web-backend

Tags: database, backend, password-protection

I am looking for a safe way to save credentials (like SSH credentials) in the backend of a Webserver (which would be **Node.js** in my case).

I already thought about hashing, but then you have to enter the password every time and it should work without entering the password again.

Comment: Whatever way you or anyone else chooses for whatever use case/solution: Never ever save passwords in an unencrypted way, nowhere.

Comment: @CodeShark Ok, how should I encrypt the passwords so that i can also use them for authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SSH

For SSH credentials, I would recommend you Setup Passwordless SSH.

On server you/the application will use to SSH into the target server

### Step 1: Generate a key pair

`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa # press enter on all prompts`

The above command will generate SSH RSA private and public keys under the user’s home directory, /root/.ssh/. The private key, id_rsa has to be kept secure on the node. The public key, id_rsa.pub should be copied over to the target server that want to be accessed passwordlessly.

### Step 2: Copy the SSH public key to the target server

`$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa <ip_address_of_the_target_server>`

The command `ssh-copy-id` will simply copy the public key from the source server and add it into the destination server’s authorized key list, default to `~/.ssh/autohorized_keys` of the authenticated SSH user. If password authentication is disabled, then a manual copy is required. On application node, copy the content of SSH public key located at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and paste it into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of the target now.

For more info on passwordless SSH check out this article: https://www.strongdm.com/blog/ssh-passwordless-login

## Other Credentials

For other credentials, more secure approaches would be to use

- Environment Variables: Use a library like `dotenv` to load them securely during runtime.
- Secure Credential Management Services: Dedicated services like AWS Secrets Manager, Azure Key Vault, or Google Cloud Secret Manager.
- Session-Based Tokens: Instead of storing raw credentials, utilize temporary session tokens for authentication.

I hope all this helps.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your fast and helpful answer. Secondly, I have another question: Is it secure to enter the ssh-password in my Web-App and send it in cleartext to the backend of my server and there run the ssh-keyless setup?

Comment: No, it is highly insecure. Any attacker who manages to intercept the communication between your browser and the server can easily capture your password in plain text. Also accidental exposure can happen, like logging the password in plain text.